# How to write an ISAPI plugin?

Tags: iis

Any links/Turorials avalable? I want to write a simple ISAPI plugin for IIS6.0.

Prefered language c++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a quick (and simple) ISAPI Filter example. I found it very useful when trying to write my first ISAPI plugin.
http://blogs.msdn.com/rakkimk/archive/2007/03/01/writing-a-simple-isapi-filter.aspx

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio used to have an ISAPI wizard which was great for writing plugins.  If you have 6.0, it might still be there.  VS 2003 has one under MFC for ISAPI with MFC support (not hard to remove if you don't want it).

If you are doing an Extension (not a filter) -- here is the minimal code you need:

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.platformsdk.internet.server.isapi-dev/browse_thread/thread/d29e1a767cbb4717